# Como manter os valores do input quando o usuário ir para outra página

Tags: php, html

Bom, montei um `form` bem simples para explicar meu problema.

```
<?php
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action', FILTER_DEFAULT);

if ((!empty($action)) && ( $action === "add")) {
?>
    <script>
        alert('ERRO');
        window.history();
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>


<form action="form.php?action=add" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="senha">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Quando há algum erro no meu formulário eu envio um `alert` para o usuário e ele é redirecionado para página anterior para que corrija o erro. O problema é que todos os dados do formulário são perdidos quando ele retorna. Existe alguma maneira de resolver isto? Uma maneira em que os dados sejam mantidos e só sejam apagados quando o formulário estiver correto?

Comment: isso não resolve meu problema, pois em alguns input já uso o `value` para carregar informações.

Comment: Se você entender como funciona compreenderá que pode resolver sim. Independente das distintas situações, a técnica é a mesma. Note que ainda pode resolver com Ajax, Cookies ou Sessions. O Ajax pode ser mais interessante pois não redireciona a página. Assim os dados persistem, além de economizar tráfego de dados.

Comment: e se ao invés de window.history vc usar window.location? então adicionar os campos que foram inseridos como query string... com isso ser eles vierem vc carrega no seu form...  algo do tipo window.location= document.referrer + '?index=1';

Comment: @h3nr1ke, o form action está levando para a mesma página.. Não há necessidade de redirecionar. Basta pegar os valores de $_POST... A edição do título desfigurou o contexto, dando margem a interpretação errônea.

Answer (score 1):

Troque `window.history()` por `window.history.back()` (equivale a clicar no botão Voltar do navegador), quando você usa o botão voltar do navegador ou mesmo a função `back` o próprio navegador recupera os dados do `<form>` (desde que a requisição tenha vindo pelo próprio `<form>`)

```
<?php
$action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action', FILTER_DEFAULT);

if ((!empty($action)) && ( $action === "add")) {
?>
    <script>
        alert('ERRO');
        window.history.back();
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>

<form action="form.php?action=add" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nome">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="senha">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Sobre a *API history*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History#Methods

Comment: deu certo em partes, todos os campos ficaram mantidos, porém o se senha foi apagado, como mantenho ele também?

Comment: @HugoBorges isso é questão de segurança, nenhum navegador mantém estes dados na camada que entendemos como "front-end", se notar em formulários de cadastro como do Gmail e Yahoo quando erra algo quase todo form é recuperado, com exceção da "senha" e do "repita a senha" (ambos usam `<input type="password">`), não é grande segurança, mas é algo padrão do input=password, eu posso até lhe dar uma sugestão, mas só se realmente você achar que é algo muito necessário, se for um form de login eu não recomendaria forçar isto

Comment: entendo, bom em questão do `<input type="password">` tudo bem, o problema e que uso um auto-complete. E quando o a algo errado o input dele é apagado, queria que esse input não fosse apagado.

Comment: Mas a opção de autocompletar senhas é ação do usuário, o site não pode ter controle sobre isto @HugoBorges

Comment: uso o auto completar para lugar cidade e não senha. Ai quando a algo errado o usuário tem que informar a cidade novamente.

Comment: @HugoBorges é que você meio que **mudou de assunto**, esta parte do autocompletar com cidade também não está no corpo da pergunta, pela lógica o .back deveria funcionar, se puder mostrar como esta em um exemplo simples eu posso testar e ver o que é possivel fazer.

Comment: bom acho melhor postar outra pergunta, vou fazer um exemplo e postar ok.

Comment: @HugoBorges não acho que seja necessário, inclusive se for um problema real eu até posso votar para reabrir a pergunta, pois parece diferente da outra que marcaram aqui